# +1 to data column using SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to create a simple button, that when clicked, adds 1 to the related column. I use a dropdown box to select the ID, then add 1 to the value. However, I am presented with the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

and it highlights `cm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

I have gone through several attempts at this but it's getting me a little confused as to why I can't simply run the SQL statement.

Here is the code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE fixedBugs SET Success = Success + 1 WHERE Fixed_ID = '" + comboBox1.Text, mySqlConnection);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch (SqlCeException) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: `'" + comboBox1.Text` -- you have an extra apostrophe or you need a closing one -- depends on the data type.  Also look into using parameterized queries -- much safer.

Comment: Thankyou - this has helped a lot! Still trying to get it to input data into the database though.

Answer (score 2):

Your command has a opening apostrophe which is not being closed. This should fix it.

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE fixedBugs SET Success = Success + 1 WHERE Fixed_ID = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'", mySqlConnection);
```

But that's a security issue since the user can manage to add extra commands to your query, which could ruin your entire database.

This is a better solution since using parameters is more safe.

```
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE fixedBugs SET Success = Success + 1 WHERE Fixed_ID = @fixedid;", mySqlConnection);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fixedid", comboBox1.Text);
```

This will prevent future headaches.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements) has better detailed answers that may help enlighten your mind...

Comment: This is a bad answer. What about security issue?

Comment: Well I'm pointing out his error, the security issue is something I can add to the answer but he is asking about the error.

Comment: This has solved the error - however nothing is being input into the database

Comment: Yes, but not working code is better than working one with security issue ;)

Comment: I'll improve my answer :)

Comment: As you can see I wrote `bad answer` not `wrong answer`. So improving can make it better ;)

Comment: Nevermind - I didn't have a default value set on my database so it was trying to +1 to null, my bad. I will select this answer - thankyou Phiter

Comment: @MattMurphy, I'm glad that I have helped but I'm changing my answer for a better one so hang in there and try using my next solution

Answer (score 2):

```
"UPDATE fixedBugs SET Success = Success + 1 WHERE Fixed_ID = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'"
```

Need to close the string parameter with ' in query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about below things;

1. User must select a value.
2. Security
3. Dispose the command after using it.

   ```
       string selectedValue = comboBox1.Text;
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Please select something");
           return;
       }
       string sql = "UPDATE fixedBugs SET Success = ISNULL(Success,0) + 1 WHERE Fixed_ID = @selectedValue";
       try
       {
           using (SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand(sql, mySqlConnection))
           {
               SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter("@selectedvalue", SqlDbType.NText);
               cm.Parameters.Add(param);
               cm.Parameters["@selectedvalue"].Size = 50;
               cm.Parameters["@selectedvalue"].Value = selectedValue.Trim();
               cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   ```

PS: Code is not tested.